# Circuit simulation shows gain with only passive components. Why?

Tags: rf, filter, antenna, simulation, ltspice

This feels like an ignorant question, but here it goes.

I'm trying to understand the antenna circuit from the 430 MHz reference design for TI's CC1125 transceiver IC. The antenna circuit is at the bottom right of [this schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrfe1/tidrfe1.pdf). Here's a [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1125.pdf) to the datasheet for the device.

I tried to simulate the circuit's behavior in receive mode (TRX floating, in transmit mode it's grounded to protect the receiver). I made the assumption that the PA would be effectively a short to ground in transmit mode. Here's the schematic I'm using in LTSpice. The source has a 50 ohm series resistance and is set to 1 V AC.

[image: simulated schematic]

The output voltage is the voltage across L5. Here are the results of the AC sweep:

[image: sweep results]

I have a secondary request before my main question. I would appreciate help understanding the function of the circuit. I understand the general operation of the balun in the upper left, but I don't understand the purpose of L5. It shorts the receive pins together at DC, but it seems like it would seriously mess with the tuned balun operation. I assume that the lowpass filter is meant to remove harmonics. What is the purpose of the series LC elements connecting the lowpass filter to the balun? What is the purpose of the parallel LC structure connecting to the Tx pin?
This is my main question:

How is it possible that any voltage in the simulated circuit is larger than the input?

Shouldn't the output voltage have a hard limit at 0 dB (or even -6 dB with a series resistance in the source)?

Comment: Voltage gain is not the same thing as power gain.

Comment: Thanks, the power gain should just be twice the voltage gain right?

Comment: The power gain is the square of the voltage gain, *if the input and load impedances are matched*. That does not apply in your circuit.

Comment: When you say one is double the other you're probably thinking of expressing gain in dB. But then, for circuits with matching input and output impedance you should get equal numerical expressions for dB gain whether you calculate from voltage gain or power gain.

Comment: Thanks, I did a stupid in my question about power gain. What should the resistance be across L5 to make the model better reflect reality? Under receive parameters in the datasheet it says that the optimum source impedance in the 33 MHz band is "100 + j60 / 50 + j30". That looks a lot like 2 ohms to me. Why did they write it this way? Should I put 2 ohm across L5?

Comment: Is the purpose of L5 to cancel out a negative reactance in the device? Its impedance at 433 MHz (I meant to write 433 above not 33) is about 24j.

Comment: Wait, I think I figured it out. The slash is an or, not division. L5 provides the 30 ohm reactance and the antenna impedance provides the 50 ohm resistance. Yes?

Comment: Except I forgot to multiply by 2 pi and the reactance of L5 is actually 150 ohms

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible that any voltage in the simulated circuit is larger than the input?

Voltage gain is not the same as power gain, and this is exactly what happens at resonance.

Your circuit has an ac source that could potentially continuously add power to the circuit. But it has no lossy elements (resistors or resistive parastics), so there is no where for power to to be removed from the circuit. In fact, of course, this circuit has only reactive impedance so no real power is ever actually delivered by the source.

In fact you can have the voltage at an intermediate point in the circuit go to infinity even with a much simpler circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f80VsQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At resonance, the input impedance of the series LC combination goes to zero. So the current delivered by the source goes to infinity. But the impedance across C1 is not zero, so therefore the voltage at the intermediate node (where L1 and C1 are connected) goes to \$-\infty\$ at resonance.

Of course in a real circuit there would be some parasitic loss somewhere and neither could the voltage source deliver infinite current, so the actual voltages would all remain finite. But in the ideal circuit approximation, you expect the possibility of infinite voltages (or currents) at resonant frequencies.

Comment: I think I get what's going on. The inductors already have a default series resistance of a mili-ohm. I simulated the circuit you suggested with and without a series resistance. Even with a series resistance, the voltage blew up across the reactive elements. Does this mean that the inductive load of the circuit actually experiences the 10ish dB of gain at the 460 MHz operating point like the simulation suggests? I tried simulating 100kOhm load across a capacitor in a tank circuit at resonance and it experienced gain relative to the source. Is this a valid technique to get narrow band gain?

Comment: It's a way to produce high voltages, but there isn't any power gain.